# Symfony add logic to logout route

Tags: symfony, symfony4, logout, symfony-security, symfony5

In a Symfony 5.0 Application I want to add custom logic for cleanup reasons when the user loggs out.
What I have currenty is what is described in the docs:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#logging-out

As the logout() function in the SecurityController is intercepted by Symfony it won't work to add logic there.

So - where CAN I add logic which is allways executed when a user loggs out?
Couldn't find anything in the docs so far...

Comment: there is a logout listener in the security package, which you could use to inspire your listener and just prioritize it higher then the security package's. https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.0/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/LogoutListener.php

Comment: you also could add something that implements the interface mentioned in the note in your linked doc section (the `LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface`, in that interface you will also find a reference for the `LogoutHandlerInterface` - it literally says in the success handler: "If you want to only perform some logout related clean-up task, use the
LogoutHandlerInterface instead.")

Comment: Yes i read that too - but it sounds as if this was kicking in when the logout is done - and therefore I can't access the user which was logged in (which I need to).

Comment: Regarding your first suggestion - I am unsure on how to do that... Any hints?

Comment: The LogoutHandlerInterface (https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Logout/LogoutHandlerInterface.php) has a `TokenInterface`, from which you can `getUser()`, which should work.

Comment: the logout listener is probably listening on all kernel request events (https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-request), and its `supports` method (see abstract listener in the same folder) will filter everything out except the app_logout route. read up on event listeners in symfony, you should be able to work it out from there. but to be honest, I would go the LogoutHandlerInterface route ...

Comment: I did go the LogoutHandlerInterface way. Works very well. If you want write an answere - I'll check it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the best option is to implement the [`LogoutHandlerInterface`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Logout/LogoutHandlerInterface.php) referenced slightly indirectly on the [symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#logging-out) you mentioned (it mentions the `LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface`, which has a comment regarding the [`LogoutHandlerInterface`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Logout/LogoutHandlerInterface.php): "If you want to only perform some logout related clean-up task, use the LogoutHandlerInterface instead.")

To me, it feels like an event handler, but it doesn't use the event system, so ... whatever.

Nevertheless, the arguments provided to your `LogoutHandler` will receive a [`TokenInterface`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/TokenInterface.php) which has `TokenInterface::getUser()` which returns the current  user. (dependency injection on the constructor should provide you with additional services and stuff)

The alternative would be to implement an EventListener for the [kernel request event](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-request) - which the `LogoutListener` of the `symfony/security` package uses to manage logouts. You would have to add the same logic as the `LogoutListener` and probably have to make it trigger before the `LogoutListener`, this is however a slightly more convoluted way and I would really use the `LogoutHandler`.